# PHP, regex and multi-level dashes and grouping together according to string occurrence

Tags: php, regex, string, grouping

I have a string which looks like this:

```
15-02-01-0000 
15-02-02-0000
15-02-03-0000 
15-02-04-0000 
15-02-05-0000 
15-02-10-0000 
15-02-10-9100 
15-02-10-9101 
15-15-81-0000 
15-15-81-0024
```

So the expected output would be:
All account grouping separated by "-" dashes for example: `15-02-01-0000` there is 3 grouping

- start with 15
- start with 15-02
- start with 15-02-01

So the expected output would be:

First it will show

```
15  --> All account start with "15"
  15-02 --> All account start with "15-02"
    15-02-01 -- All accounts start with "15-02-01"
      15-02-01-0000 
    15-02-02 -- All accounts start with 15-02-02
      15-02-02-0000
    15-02-03 -- onwards like above
      15-02-03-0000 
    15-02-04 
      15-02-04-0000 
    15-02-05 
      15-02-05-0000 
    15-02-10 
      15-02-10-0000 
      15-02-10-9100 
      15-02-10-9101 
  15-15 
    15-15-81 
      15-15-81-0000 
      15-15-81-0024
```

I tried to use `substr`:

```
$res = substr("15-15-81-0024",3,2);
if ($res == "15") {

} else if ($res < 10 && $res != 00) {

} else {

}
```

But not working to put grouping.
Could you please suggest any good way?

Comment: Did my post answered you?

Comment: Yes, that's acceptable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break each data by `-` and build the array in as much as needed. Notice the use of **`&`** in the code as using reference to result array.

Example:

```
$str = "15-02-01-0000,15-02-02-0000,15-02-03-0000,15-02-04-0000,15-02-05-0000,15-02-10-0000,15-02-10-9100,15-02-10-9101,15-15-81-0000,15-15-81-0024";
$arr = explode(",", $str);
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $e) { // for each line in your data
    $a = explode("-", $e); //break to prefix
    $current = &$res; 
    while(count($a) > 1) { // create the array to that specific place if needed
        $key = array_shift($a); // take the first key
        if (!isset($current[$key])) // if the path not exist yet create empty array 
            $current[$key] = array();
        $current = &$current[$key];
    }
    $current[] = $e; // found the right path so add the element
}
```

The full result will be in `$res`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something along the lines of:
Could be more efficient if more time was spent on it.

```
<?php

$random = '15-02-01-0000 
15-02-02-0000
15-02-03-0000 
15-02-04-0000 
15-02-05-0000 
15-02-10-0000 
15-02-10-9100 
15-02-10-9101 
15-15-81-0000 
15-15-81-0024';

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $random);
$accounts = return_count($lines);
var_dump($accounts);

function return_count($lines){
    $count_accounts = array();
    $possibilties = array();
    if(is_array($lines) && !empty($lines)){
        foreach($lines as $val){
            $line = explode('-', $val);
            array_push($possibilties, $line[0], $line[0] . '-' . $line[1], $line[0] . '-' . $line[1] . '-' . $line[2]);
        }
        foreach($possibilties as $pos){
            if(!isset($count_accounts[$pos])){ $count_accounts[$pos] = 0;}
            if(search_array($pos, $lines)){
                $count_accounts[$pos]++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $count_accounts;
}

function search_array($string, $array){
    $found = 0;
    if(is_array($array) && !empty($array)){
       foreach($array as $val){
            if (strpos($val, $string) !== false) {
                $found = 1;
            }
       }
       if($found == 1){
            return true;
       }else{
            return false;
       } 
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

Which returns:

```
array (size=10)
  15 => int 10
  '15-02' => int 8
  '15-02-01' => int 1
  '15-02-02' => int 1
  '15-02-03' => int 1
  '15-02-04' => int 1
  '15-02-05' => int 1
  '15-02-10' => int 3
  '15-15' => int 2
  '15-15-81' => int 2
```

Comment: This only count but not group - I am not sure this what the OP wanted...

Comment: @Second2None Its only count not grouping, is it possible to make grouping as well?